# Nested jade blocks are not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

If I have a jade setup with 3 files as follows:

1.

```
//layout.jade

doctype html
html
  body
    block content
```

2.

```
//index.jade
extends layout

block content
  h1 Animals
  block cat
  block dog
```

3.

```
//animals.jade
extends index

block cat
  p Meow

block dog
  p Bark
```

The 'cat' and 'dog' blocks do not render any text to the view.  Is there anything wrong with including a jade file that defines multiple blocks as I've done above?

I realize that I could split the 'cat' and 'dog' blocks into two separate .jade files and then include them separately, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not.

Comment: then how did you solve this?

Comment: I didn't.  I moved on to something else.  I'll probably re-visit it at some point though.

Answer (score 0):

In the animals.jade, you want to append something to the block.
so try this:

```
//animals.jade
extends index
block append cat
  p Meow
block append dog
  p Bark
```

Comment: I gave this a try, but unfortunately it didn't work.  This really seems like it should be possible...

Comment: And the index.jade should be modified:block append content

Comment: This didn't work either.  I've tried replacing all of the "block" calls with "block append", and it still doesn't seem to render the block.  With the exception of the "block content" call in layout.jade.  The content block contained within index.jade is correctly included into layout.jade, however, the "cat" and "dog" blocks are *not* included into index.jade.

Comment: Please have a look at the tutorial in the page: [http://segmentfault.com/a/1190000000357534]. Search the "block" and you will see the correct use of block.

Comment: I skimmed this page, but it doesn't seem to cover multi-level nested blocks (File A includes Block B, and Block B includes Block C) - just one level (File A includes Block B).  From what I've read, the code that I've written in my original post should be correct...with or without the "append" key.

Comment: Without the use of "append", the block is redefined in the current file,and it will override its previous definition.

Comment: I tried replacing *all* "block" calls with "block append" calls, but I still get the same results.  I also tried using a "block" call to pull in the content block, and "block append" calls to pull in the cat and dog blocks.  Neither approach resulted in the cat and dog blocks being rendered.

Comment: In the animals.jade , try this:  `//animals.jade 
extends index 
block append content
    block append cat
      p Meow
    block append dog
      p Bark`

Comment: The formatting didn't show up in your previous comment, but I'm assuming you were intending for the "block append cat" and "block append dog" to be indented underneath the "block append content".  In any case, I tried it with and without the indentation, and neither of them worked unfortunately...

Comment: The code that I'm using doesn't actually have those file name comments.  I just put the comments in my example above for clarity.  The comments aren't the cause of my issue.

Comment: I tried your orginal code just now and they run correctly. The block cat and dog can render to Meow and Bark. And when I add the append ,it also run well as expected.

Comment: Just so that we're on the same page, I completely removed the code that I was using, and replaced it with the cat and dog example that I posted above.  I copied it exactly as I wrote it in my original post, and the only text I see rendered to the page is "Animals".  I don't see "Meow" or "Bark".